# Use Find and xargs to delete dups in arraylist

Tags: bash

I have arraylist of files and I am trying to use rm with xargs to remove files like:

```
    dups=["test.csv","man.csv","teams.csv"]
```

How can I pass the complete `dups` array to `find` and delete these files?

I want to make changes below to make it work

```
    find ${dups[@]} -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: How is this related to [java] ? (Try using `-delete` option with `find`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get unique values from an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648410/how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: so "${dups[@]}" - Syntax for working with shell arrays. I want to pass Java arraylist dups in this rm cmd as I am executing command in between my java code

Comment: The initial arguments (so called _starting-points_) of `find` are meant to be **directories**, not files. Have a  look at the _find_ man-page!

Comment: in bash, `dups=["test.csv","man.csv","teams.csv"]` isn't an array declaration; it should be `dups=( "test.csv" "man.csv" "teams.csv" )` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `find` command is wrong.

```
# XXX buggy: read below
find foo bar baz -type f -print0
```

means look in the *paths* `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, and print any actual files within those. (If one of the paths is a directory, it will find all files within that directory. If one of the paths is a file in the current directory, it will certainly find it, but then what do you need `find` for?)

If these are files in the current directory, simply

```
rm -- "${dups[@]}"
```

(notice also how to properly quote the array expansion).

If you want to look in all subdirectories for files with these names, you will need something like

```
find . -type f \( -name "test.csv" -o -name "man.csv" -o -name "teams.csv" \) -delete
```

or perhaps

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex '.*/(test\.csv|man\.csv|teams\.csv)' -delete
```

though the `-regex` features are somewhat platform-dependent (try `find -E` instead of `find -regextype egrep` on *BSD/MacOS to enable ERE regex support).

Notice also how `find` has a built-in predicate `-delete` so you don't need the external utility `rm` at all. (Though if you wanted to run a different utility, `find -exec utility {} +` is still more efficient than `xargs`. Some really old `find` implementations didn't have the `+` syntax for `-exec` but you seem to be on Linux where it is widely supported.)

Building this command line from an array is not entirely trivial; I have [proposed a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955313/how-to-read-out-a-file-line-by-line-and-for-every-line-do-a-search-with-find-and/71104113#71104113) which has a solution to a similar problem. But of course, if you are building the command from Java, it should be easy to figure out how to do this on the Java side instead of passing in an array to Bash; and then, you don't need Bash at all (you can pass this to `find` directly, or at least use `sh` instead of `bash` because the command doesn't require any Bash features).

I'm not a Java person, but from Python this would look like

```py
import subprocess

command = ["find", ".", "-type", "f"]
prefix = "("
for filename in dups:
    command.extend([prefix, "-name", filename])
    prefix = "-o"
command.extend([")", "-delete"])
subprocess.run(command, check=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Notice how the backslashes and quotes are not necessary when there is no shell involved.