# Concatenate (using bash) all file names in subdirectories with option

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have directory work_dir, and there are some subdirectories inside. And inside subdirectories there are zip archives. I can see all zip archives in terminal:

```
find . -name *.zip
```

The output:

```
./folder2/sub/dir/test2.zip
./folder3/test3.zip
./folder1/sub/dir/new/test1.zip
```

---

Now I want to concatinate all these file names in single row with some option. For example I want single row:

```
my_command -f ./folder2/sub/dir/test2.zip -f ./folder3/test3.zip -f ./folder1/sub/dir/new/test1.zip -u user1 -p pswd1
```

In this example:
`my_command` is some command
`-f` the option
`-u user1` another option with value
`-p pswd1` another option with value

Can you help me please, how can I do this in Linux BASH ?

Comment: A fundamental but possibly important corner case is what would happen if the resulting command line is too long. Is it acceptable to run `mycommand` multiple times if required? Like if your files are "foo.zip", "bar.zip", and "baz.zip", you would run `mycommand -f foo.zip -f bar.zip etc` and then `mycommand -f baz.zip etc` in a separate invocation if your maximum allowed command line length was very very short.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104113/874188 has some discussion around this but it's not really a duplicate per se (not least because the OP never completely settled on what worked for them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making a bash script.

1. Make a new file called whatever.sh
2. Type `chmod +x ./whatever.sh` so it becomes executable on the terminal
3. Add the BASH scripting as shown below..

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get all the zip files from your FolderName
files="`find ./FolderName -name *.zip`"

# Loop through the files and build your args
arg=""
for file in $files; do
    arg="$arg -f $file"
done

# Run your command
mycommand $arg -u user1 -p pswd1
```

Comment: This is running into https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: thank you @AndrewFenn . This is the simpliest  and best solution!

Comment: This will fail if a filename contains any whitespace character.

Comment: It will fail in quite a few ways. My aim with the answer wasn't to provide an exhaustive and comprehensively battle tested script. Just to provide enough information for them to get started to be able to further go and develop it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

One way is: (updated per @M. Nejat Aydin comments)

```
find . -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 printf -- '-f\0%s\0' | xargs -0 -n100000 my_command -u user1 -p pswd1
```

Note that `-n100000` parameter forces all output of the previous xargs to be executed on the same line with the assumption that number of findings will be less than `100000`.

I used null terminated versions (notice: `-0` flag, `-print0`) because file names can contain spaces.

Comment: There must have been a whitespace between `"` and `'`, or before `-f` (that is, the argument of `printf` must have been `'-f "%s" '` or `' -f "%s"'`) in order to work it properly. But that will be still broken; it will fail when a filename contains a `"` character, for instance.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin will single quoting filename help?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin corrected the other issue. Thanks

Comment: Single quoting will fail if a filename contains a `'` (single-quote) character. The only safe character, in this context, is `NUL` (`'\0'`) since a pathname cannot contain it (except the terminating null byte). Something like that might work: `... | xargs -0 -n1 printf -- '-f\0%s\0' | xargs -0 ...`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin but that will make the -f and filename to appear as a single argument to mycommand. That was my first answer and i later changed it because of this

Comment: No, it won't. Notice the `-0` in the second `xargs`. And, `-n1` won't be needed.

Comment: Also note that there are two `\0`s in the argument of `printf`, which will separate the `-f` and the filename.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin yes you are right! I missed the second \0. I will update it. Thanks

Comment: If you have a lot of arguments, `xargs` could still end up splitting between an `-f` and its argument; it's actually fairly likely to happen if your data exceeds `ARG_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bash script that should do what you wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=user1
passwd=pswd1

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do
  args+=(-f "$files")
done < <(find . -name '*.zip' -print0)

args=("${args[@]}" -u "$user" -p "$passwd")

##: Just for the human eye to see the output, 
##: change this line of code according to the comment below.   
printf 'mycommand %s\n' "${args[*]}"
```

---

The output should be in one-line, like what you wanted, but do change the last line from

```
printf 'mycommand %s\n' "${args[*]}"
```

into

```
mycommand "${args[@]}"
```

If you actually want to execute `mycommand` with the arguments.

---

Change the value of `user` and `passwd` too.

---

- A `while` + [read](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) loop was used with [IFS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS).

See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

---

- Why the last line should be change.
  See [Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments)

---

- Shell quoting is a basic but common mistake when dealing with spaces in file/path name.

See [How can I find and safely handle file names containing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

---

Also the [find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) command/utiliy.

---

- The construct `"${args[@}"` is an array.

See [Array1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) [Array2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Arrays) [Array3](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays)

Comment: You went through all this trouble, but then you use `"${args[*]}"` instead of the correct `"${args[@]}"`

Comment: @tripleee, Just to show the outcome/output, is all. Also `"${args[@]}"` is included in my post/answer.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Still, would it not be simpler and less error-prone to use `"${args[@]}"` there too?

Comment: I just want to show/answer the _For example I want single row:_ question/request from the OP.